# Does this Verilog code infer a latch?

Tags: verilog, schematics, latch, vlsi

I wrote down these lines intentionally avoiding to reset the output `o` when `rstb` is asserted:

```
module top_trial (
  input        clk,
  input        rstb,
  input        a,
  output reg   o
);
reg ff;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rstb)
  begin
    if (!rstb)
      ff <= 1'b0;
    else
      begin
        ff <= a;
        o  <= ff;
      end 
  end
endmodule // top_trial
```

By using Real Intent's Ascent I retrieved this schematic:
[image]

The question is: do you think the multiplexer has a chance to be replaced by a latch (with enable) during the synthesis phase or by using another schematic tool?

Comment: You will never infer a latch in a clocked process because latches are asynchronous constructs.

Comment: Now the multiplexer is effectively a clock enable for the flip flop.

Comment: OP and @TomCarpenter, you'll never infer anything in Verilog or VHDL, the synthesis tool makes the inference - you imply things in HDLs. (I imply - you infer, a basic of English) :-)

Comment: @TonyM when I read through Verilog code, I infer what it will produce. Neither I nor the synthesis tool will infer a latch from a clocked process... two can play at the semantics game ;).

Comment: @TomCarpenter, that's true - you do what the synthesis tool or simulator will do and infer from it. Whereas Verilog/VHDL imply things. My point was just on the English, nothing to do with the Verilog but it wasn't a major thing here :-) (Can't say about the FF/latch - my VHDL's very good but my Verilog's rubbish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no latch in this design. All updates to the state variables `ff` and `o` (except for the asynchronous reset of `ff`) are controlled by the clock.